# Number of values within a specific range in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `T`. I am trying to find the number of values within a specified range through `T1` but I am getting an error. I present the expected output.

```
T=np.array([4.7,5.1,2.9])
T1=np.flatnonzero(2<T<3,3<T<4,4<T<5)
print(T1)
```

The error is

```
in <module>
    T1=np.flatnonzero(2<T<3,3<T<4,4<T<5)

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

The expected output is

```
T1=[1,0,1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `flatnonzero` has nothing to do with what you want.
- Furthermore, the error 'The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous' comes from the double condition 2<T<3: you need to separate it into 2 conditions: `(2<T) & (T<3)`.
- `T[(2<T) & (T<3)]` will yield an array of the values of T respecting the conditions.

Thus, if you need to count the elements of T that are between 2 and 3, you can do:

```
len(T[(2 <T) & (T < 3)])
```

To obtain what you want, you could then do this:

```
Ranges = [(2,3),(3,4),(4,5)]
T1 = [len(T[(a < T) & (T < b)]) for a,b in Ranges]

print(T1)
# [1, 0, 1]
```

To print the actual values fitting the criteria, you can do:

```
T2 = [list(T[(a < T) & (T < b)]) for a,b in Ranges]

print(T2)
# [[2.9], [], [4.7]]
```

To get the corresponding indices, we finally have a use for `flatnonzero`:

```
T3 = [list(np.flatnonzero((a < T) & (T < b))) for a,b in Ranges]

print(T3)
# [[2], [], [0]]
```

Comment: This works. Is it also possible to print the corresponding indices? For example, corresponding to ```[[2.9],[],[4.7]]```, the indices should be ```[2,None,0]```.

Answer (score 2):

You need to split the ranges to two and `sum` the results. You also don't need to use `np.flatnonzero` here, it's not really connected to what you are doing

```
T1 = ((2 < T) & (T < 3)).sum(), ((3 < T) & (T < 4)).sum(), ((4 < T) & (T < 5)).sum()
print(T1) # (1, 0, 1)
```

Comment: Nice logic; .sum() is indeed more efficient than my .len() method :)

Comment: This works. How do I also print the actual values meeting this criterion? For instance, ```[2.9,None,4.7]```.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you expect this to work?

1. It breaks in `2<T<3`. You can't use this kind of syntax in `numpy`. You should to replace `2<T<3` with `(2<T) & (T<3)` which is equivalent of [`np.logical_and`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html). So you need the truth value of two boolean arrays (2<T) AND (T<3) element-wise as it said in docummentation.
2. [`np.flatnonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html) takes one single argument. If you want to plug in several conditions, use `|` (or [`np.logical_or`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html)) to get the truth value of two boolean arrays `arr1` OR `arr2` element-wise.

```
cond1 = (2<T) & (T<3) 
cond2 = (3<T) & (T<4) 
cond3 = (4<T) & (T<5)
```

Number of conditions fulfilled for each value:

```
>>> np.sum([cond1, cond2, cond3], axis=0)
array([1, 0, 1])
```

Arrays of values that satisfies each condition:

```
>>> T[cond1], T[cond2], T[cond3]
(array([2.9]), array([], dtype=float64), array([4.7]))
```

Arrays of indices of values that satisfies each condition:

```
>>> np.flatnonzero(cond1), np.flatnonzero(cond2), np.flatnonzero(cond3)
(array([2], dtype=int64), array([], dtype=int64), array([0], dtype=int64))
```

Comment: Though it's related, this does not do what the OP wanted.

Comment: @Swifty Thanks for notice, fixed. It gets similar to your answer, I only use an approach from `numpy` side.